# How do you make multiple circles in css

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I try to make multiple circles in css and then link them to my html file.
the code looks like this:

```
.circle{
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
background-color: red;
}
```

But then when I try to make another circle (by using the same 'circle' class), it interferes with some of my javascript code, some of which are my variables. So I was wondering, if there was a second circle tag that did the same thing.

Comment: What you have shown here works. Therefore something in your JavaScript is *badly* wrong for it to break something so fundamentally simple. We need to see more code to attempt debugging, preferably a live example.

Comment: all i want to know is if there is another way to make a circle without using the tag 'circle' in css @NiettheDarkAbsol

Comment: You can! Just create another class that does the same?

Comment: Can you give me an example please? @kabooya

Comment: If you really need an “example” on how to apply the same formatting via a different class, then this suggest that you severely lack basic knowledge about working with CSS. And in that case, you should go and read up on it a bit more on your own first. This is not a tutorial site, we are not here to teach basics.

Answer (score 1):

You have a css class as an example, classes are reusable in your HTML code. For example:

```
<div class="circle">One circle</div>
<div class="circle">Another circle</div>
```

Just apply the class to the element either in your JavaScript if you render elements there, or straight up in your HTML as shown above.

On another note, to get rounded edges on your element you can add a border radius in your css class:

```
.circle{
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
background-color: red;
border-radius: 50%; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new div in your HTML, with another class type, f.e. cirlce2

```
<div class="circle2"></div>
```

Then just copy paste your CSS:

```
.circle2{
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
background-color: red;
border-radius: 100%;
}
```

Comment: i have completly no idea why but css doesnt think of it as a circle, but as a rectangle. Why does this happen. I have tried what you just did. double checked it all to make sure but it doesnt reconize 'circle2' as a circle.

Comment: Ow, see edited code!